# QGIS Resource Sharing urlopen error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I get an error message if I try to install some symbols in QGIS with QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin. My System is Windows 10 and QGIS 2.18.19

Could someone give a hint to solve that Problem?

[image: urlopen error]

Comment: So called "1407742E" error problem... since this February. Git does not accept TLS1 / TLS1.1 anymore. I am struggling with this, too. A workaround is to visit the original git site and download from there directly.

Comment: Have your tried with a recent version of QGIS and the QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin? The current version of the plugin is 0.15.1.